# How to dynamically show an image on certain child views of a expandable listview

Tags: android, listview

I am trying to figure out how to show an image on only some of the child views in the expandable listview. I need to set it based on the group and child index. I tried doing it by index like this:

```
public View getChildView(final int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
        boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final String laptop = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.child_item, null);
    }

    ImageView email = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.email);
    //this shows the email icon where applicable
    if (groupPosition == 0 && childPosition == 0 ){
        email.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    if (groupPosition == 2 && childPosition == 0 ){
        email.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    item.setText(Html.fromHtml(laptop));
    return convertView;
}
```

But when you start scrolling down it starts setting different ones to GONE because of how the recycling works. How can I fix this to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to recycle views, from the looks of it. Don't do it if you don't have to. (All the docs make it sound like a requirement and all the examples use it, but it isn't required. It's just "good practice" but when a "good practice" takes 10x as long as getting the job done should take, it really isn't a good practice is it??)

The concept behind recycling has to do with scrolling through a very long list of items. If your list contains only a few items, you don't need to do it.

If you ultimately need to, this will fix your code:

```
ImageView email = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.email);
//this shows the email icon where applicable
if (groupPosition == 0 && childPosition == 0 ){
    email.setVisibility(View.GONE);
} else
if (groupPosition == 2 && childPosition == 0 ){
    email.setVisibility(View.GONE);
} else {
    email.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

If you don't want to recycle views, you just ignore `convertView` like this:

```
public View getChildView(final int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
        boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final String laptop = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();

    View newView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.child_item, null);

    ImageView email = (ImageView) newView.findViewById(R.id.email);
    //this shows the email icon where applicable
    if (groupPosition == 0 && childPosition == 0 ){
        email.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else
    if (groupPosition == 2 && childPosition == 0 ){
        email.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else {
        email.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    item.setText(Html.fromHtml(laptop));
    return newView;
}
```

Comment: hmm ok that worked easily, I was unaware I had the option to not recycle views. Is that an easy change to not recycle them?

Comment: I edited my answer to demo how to not recycle - convertView is used for recycling and it can be a pain...